# JAVA trying to fetch records from excel sheets

Tags: java, excel

```
public class sample {
    private static Workbook workbook;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C://Users//chakku//Desktop//ch//updated/TestReport Lang Funda1.xls");

            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

            Sheet sh = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            for(int i=0;i<=sh.getLastRowNum();i++) {
                int z=i+1;
                Cell cell = sh.getRow(z).getCell(1);
                if(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK == cell.getCellType()) {
                    System.out.println("3");
                }else {
                    System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
                }
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }  
    } 
}
```

I don't know what's wrong but at the end when all records are fetched it's printing NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Error in constructing the access index - use this:

```
 for(int z= 1;z<=sh.getLastRowNum();z++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

if say you just have two rows, then sh.getLastRowNum() will return you one (as it starts count with 0), and you will try to access it like

```
for(int i=0;i<=sh.getLastRowNum();i++) {
    int z=i+1;
    Cell cell = sh.getRow(z).getCell(1);
```

So for i = 1, you are accessing 2nd row (`sh.getRow(2)`), which doesnt exists as you should start with 0th row. You should do the following:

```
for(int i=0;i<=sh.getLastRowNum();i++) {
    Cell cell = sh.getRow(z).getCell(1);
```